# How likely is BigDecimal to cause memory issues for a POS program?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, currency, bigdecimal

I understand that BigDecimal is the most accurate way to express currency because treating currency values as a floating-point data type tends to cause rounding errors. However, I also understand that BigDecimal calculations require more memory. That said, is using BigDecimal instead of float or double really the best practice for programs that deal with currency values? If I make a program that prints off an itemized receipt for each order at a restaurant, am I more likely to run out of memory if I use BigDecimal or more likely to get rounding errors if I use floating-point values instead?

(Note: "What to do with Java BigDecimal performance?" is a slightly similar question, but I am more concerned with the least risky option for a relatively simple fast food transaction.)

Comment: Assuming you're running the program on a computer that's not at least 35 years old, you won't run out of my memory by using `BigDecimal`. You are much more likely to lose precision when working with `float` or `double` than to run out of memory.

Comment: No, the most accurate way to represent currency is either to use a third party library like Joda Money or create your own currency class that suits your particular needs. Internally using integers to represent dollars as cents and dinars as darahim seems to me to be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless your program is dealing with millions of BigDecimals at a time, you won't really notice a difference in memory consumption.

And if you do run a service with such a throughput, you can surely afford to buy an extra gigabyte of RAM instead of running into lawsuits for incorrect calculations ;-).